# Configuring a blog/book page with React GH Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages, gitbook

I'm looking for a way to have a personal blog, in book-format, hosted on GH Pages and built with React. My domain is at `[username].github.io` and I have links set up with `BrowserRouter`. I'd like `[username].github.io/blog` to be the home page for blogs for redirection and `[username].github.io/blog/postid` to be the home page for each post, and navigation occurs from there. How is the best way to achieve this? Two examples:

- https://github.com/NanXiao/strace-little-book
- https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/

I was unable to tell how the second was published, but for the first, how would I go about integrating Gitbook with my personal React SPA on GH Pages and having the blog pages as I specified? I'm unsure from reading the documentation, as it seems oriented to a singular book deployment.

I have my GH Pages app deployed with the following instructions (with minor optimizations for linkage and correctness):

- https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages